# How to delete all rows from a table which references another table?

Tags: mysql

```
DELETE FROM hk_qa.shipping_order_lifecycle
WHERE create_dt < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 4 MONTH)
```

But its showing below error

> Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`hk_qa`.`lifecycle_reason`, CONSTRAINT
>   `fk_lifecycle_reason_shipping_order_lifecycle1` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`shipping_order_lifecycle_id`) REFERENCES `shipping_order_lifecycle`
>   (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACT)

Comment: You may need to remove the constraint.

Comment: No i cant as all of these tables are working on companies main production site i just want to delete some rows from that parent, without removing constraint is there any other way to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

If you have child records referencing the given records in `shipping_order_lifecycle` table, then either you need to delete the child records first, or change the foreign key constraint to cascade deletes using `ON DELETE CASCADE` in place of `ON DELETE NO ACT`.

I do not suggest to remove the constraint and do the delete because that would result in orphans records in the child tables and you do not want that.

Comment: This would be your answer. [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234)